# unknown modifier error in my preg_replace attempt

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

so I did

```
$subject = 'sakdlfjsalfdjslfad <a href="something/8230">lol is that true?</a> lalalala';

$subject = preg_replace('<a href="something\/([0-9]+)">(.+?)<\/a>', '$1', $subject);

echo $subject;
```

whereby the objective is to have $subject return

```
'sakdlfjsalfdjslfad lol is that true? lalalala'
```

but then PHP returned

```
warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '('
```

what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the pattern needs delimiters -- slashes, e.g.

```
'/<a href="something\/([0-9]+)">(.+?)<\/a>/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need delimiters around the pattern:

```
$subject = preg_replace('#<a href="something/([0-9]+)">(.+?)</a>#', '$1', $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

A PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) should be surrounded by delimiters, so

```
<a href="something\/([0-9]+)">(.+?)<\/a>
```

should be

```
/<a href="something\/([0-9]+)">(.+?)<\/a>/
```

I have used slashes (`/`) - but there are lots of choices

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is
>   enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric,
>   non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and
>   tildes (~). The following are all examples of valid delimited
>   patterns.

[here are the docs for delimiters in pregex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)